# Qt lineEdit text conversion to hex issue

Tags: qt, hex, data-conversion, qlineedit

I want to take the text from a lineEdit widget and convert it to hex.
I thought that the two following conversions have the same result but they don't.

```
1. data = QByteArray::fromHex(ui->lineEdit_send->text().toUtf8().toHex());
   qDebug() << data;

2. data = QByteArray::fromHex(ui->lineEdit_send->text().toUtf8());
   data = data.toHex();
   qDebug() << data;
```

For example, if I enter the text "$54$65", the first implementation outputs $54$65 while the second implementation outputs "5465" and I cannot understand why the '$' is not displayed.

Comment: the first statement converts the lineedit text to hex and then you convert it back. The second one first interprets the lineedit text as hex and convert the result to hex. These are two different things.

Comment: I am confused at your question about `'$' ` for me hex is `0xFF`  or `xFF`

Comment: @drescherjm I want to send hexadecimal values to a microcontroller via serial com port for example I want to send 0x54 0x65 with a separation character ($) before every hexadecimal value. So I send $54$65 to lineEdit. But since this is interpreted as string I want to take the two characters after each '$' and convert them to the hex value these two chars represent.

Comment: If you type `$54$65` in your QLineEdit that should be enough with no conversion at all. You actually don't want any hex conversion with your Qt code. Your first example converts to hex then reverts the conversion. If you are typing something else in your QLineEdit then you will need to add '$' part yourself in between each 2 character hex code.

Comment: This example may help if you are not typing the '$' in your `QLineEdit` but want Qt to add it for you: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toHex-1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toHex-1)

Comment: @drescherjm ok Thank you!